# Accessing a taken down website from the files that contains redirects

Tags: html, redirect, joomla, offline

Sorry if I sound a bit incompetent, I'm new to this.

So here's the problem:

I'm trying to access a website of which I have the files to, so that I can see how it used to be/look like. From my digging it is apparent that the website was created with Joomla. The website is no longer being hosted on the internet.

I am using XAMPP to host the website locally. However, whenever I try to access the website, it redirects me to the old internet address of the website, which, as it is no longer being hosted, ends with an error.

I did a little bit of digging into the files, and I have found that the first thing that the website loads is the index.html, which contains the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Old Website</title>
<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=http://www.oldwebsite.com.au"></HEAD>
<BODY>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I then looked a bit more and found this index.html file in every folder, redirecting to the website at every corner.

Is there any possible way to stop all this redirecting so I can access the website?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "trying to access website" ? Are you trying to access the website using its domain name ?

Comment: Probably the easiest thing would be to delete all the index.html files and replace them with the index.html files from the core of Joomla (download a fresh copy and copy that).

Comment: @Apurv - so what I have are the backups of the entire website files. I'm using XAMPP to host it locally (i.e. trying to access the website through localhost/oldwebsite/). However it appears that the first thing that accessing that website does is access the index.html file and then redirects me through to the actual internet address (which no longer exists). I need to reference some of the things in the files but I can't without viewing the website as it used to be.

Comment: @Elin hey, thanks for taking the time to help me. I downloaded a fresh copy of Joomla but the only index.html file was in the tmp folder, which was pretty much blank..
`<!DOCTYPE html><title></title>`
was all it contained.
I tried doing what you suggested, by replacing all the index.html files that I could find, yet I still for some reason could not get out of that redirect.

Comment: Truthfully those index files are only there because you don't want the server to show the list of files in the directory, and that is still extremely important in the case of the cache, media, images and tmp folders because those could contain private information or be abused. What concerns me is that the index.html would be loading.  Are you positive that code is not found in your template index file? .... Oh the other thing that has occassionally happened to me is that if the `configuration.php` file has live_site or the temp or cache paths set to the old site.

Comment: @Elin Argh it was also referenced in there, but changing the configuration.php file didn't do anything.. I've kinda given up - my experience in websites and joomla is very, very limited. I really only needed the text that was written in the website, which, after a quick google, I've found joomla actually stores server side... which I both no longer have access to, and they also said they've cleared everything. Unless there is a place where the text is actually held within the files, I guess it's kind of hopeless - Thanks for trying to help me anyways!

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you are trying to view a website you have previously downloaded and now have problems regarding the domain resolving on your device.

A workaround to access the files on your device instead redirecting to the old webserver would be following.
Create a new hostfile entry on your device where you set the domain to resolve for localhost.

Following link is a step by step tutorial for windows, ubuntu and macos.
https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/